# Comparing date time in Dart

Tags: dart

I have seen a number of examples, but I still cannot make dates comparable in Flutter (Dart).

My code is

```
    jsonData.sort((a, b) => a[DateTime.parse("date")]
        .date
        .compareTo(b[DateTime.parse("date")]));
```

The date is stored in a JSON variable called date, its is formatted as 02/02/2021, when I try to sort this, cast / parse the date it throws an exception error that suggests because date isn't an int it can't be compared.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what data structure you have but I would guess this is closer to be correct compared to your own solution:

```
    jsonData.sort((a, b) => DateTime.parse(a["date"])
        .compareTo(DateTime.parse(b["date"])));
```

The reason is that e.g. `a[DateTime.parse("date")]` means you are parsing the `String` `"date"` to a `DateTime` and uses this `DateTime` instance as the key in your `a` map. This will fail on multiple levels since the string `"date"` cannot be parsed to a `DateTime` instance and your map are properly not even taking a `DateTime` as its key.